# importing csv (magento)

Tags: magento, csv, import

I have a certain attribute `dealer_country` in my website, which is a dropdown attribute containing a list of all countries. However, in my csv file, the `dealer_country` attribute will be containing country codes(in 2-letter format). Would it be possible to import with this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is an easy way and a hard way.

If programming is your bag then you can get your attribute hooked up to the Magento country codes and have it return country names on the front end.

It would take a while to write such an ideal solution. However you can use a 3rd party import tool like 'Magmi' to get your products in without having to define your attribute values first.

Once in you can edit your attribute entries for country and, in the second column put the country names to be shown on the front end. e.g. for 'GB' in column one you have 'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland' in column two. Or for 'LY' you can add 'The Great Socialist People's Libyan Arab Jamahiriya' for column two... Oops!

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: You can build attributes that tie into your own source models, but I haven't written one in three months and, knowing MAgento, it would probably take me a week or two to get 'into the zone' where I knew what I was doing!!! Anyway, sometimes the most elegant solution isn't always the best if you want the job done.